# Numpy array/asarray leak?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, flask, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

Processing images on the server with pytorch and facing memory issues. In particular:

Scenario 1:

```
#before execution memory used is 1518
temp = PIL.Image.open(im) #no leak
del im
del temp
gc.collect()
#after execution x5 times memory used is 1518
```

Scenario 2:

```
#before execution memory used is 1518
temp = PIL.Image.open(im) #no leak
del im
temp2 = np.array(temp) #leak? (asarray has same behaviour)
del temp
temp2 = None
del temp2
gc.collect()
#after execution x5 times memory used is 2385
```

Details:

```
numpy==1.19.0
python==3.6.9
flask
apache2
libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
virtualenv
watching memory using 'watch free -m'
```

I do not think this is flask or wsgi -related

However, if I do a simple experiment in python3 environment:

```
#before execution memory used is 2418
a = [random.random()]*100000000
b = np.array(a)
del a
del b
#after execution memory used is 2418
```

Comment: Does manually calling `import gc; gc.collect()` release the memory?

Comment: @DanielS. I do call gc.collect later in code, but it does not affect the memory usage with this simple example

Comment: For the output of `free -m`, which column are you

Comment: @DanielS. 'used' column 'mem' row

Answer (score 1):

Try scenario 2 as:

```
temp = PIL.Image.open(im)
del im
temp2 = np.array(temp) 
temp2 = None
del temp
del temp2
gc.collect()
```